# rails How to pass params fro new to create block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working on a project where I want to pass :repairshop_id params to new_user_review. I am doing this by using:

```
<%= link_to 'Add A Review', new_user_review_path(@user, :repairshop_id => @repairshop.id), class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs", style: "border: #e20049" %>
```

Each review is for a user but either on his repairshop or all his listings.

In the controller for reviews, my before action should set the @parent which is either the repairshop or listing depending upon where I call the new review from (A show listing page or a show repairshop page).

On clicking the new review button the url shows: `http://localhost:3000/users/2/reviews/new?repairshop_id=3`

which means I do have the repairshop_id available.

But when I trying to set the params in the controller its evaluating to nil class.

Controller Code:

```
class ReviewsController < InheritedResources::Base

    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :update] 

    before_action :set_parent, only:  [:new, :create] 
    before_action :set_child_and_parent, only:  [:destroy, :update, :update, :edit]


    def new
        @review = Review.new        
    end

    def edit

    end

    def create
        @review = Review.new(review_params)         
        @review.user_id = current_user.id
        @review.owner_id = @owner.id        

        p "My parent is #{@parent}"

        respond_to do |format|
            if @review.save 
                format.html { redirect_to @parent, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location:@parent }
            else                
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end

    end

    def destroy

        @review.destroy
        respond_to do |format|                      
            format.html { redirect_to @parent, notice: 'Review  was successfully destroyed.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end

    end

    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @review.update(review_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @parent, notice: 'Review was updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @parent}
            else
                format.html { render :edit }
                format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    private

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:comment, :rating, :repairshop_id)
    end

    def set_child_and_parent
        @review = Review.find_by_id(params[:id])
        if params[:repairshop_id]
            @parent =  Repairshop.find_by_id(params[:repairshop_id])
        end

        if params[:listing_id]
            @parent = Listing.find_by_id(params[:listing_id])   
        end

        @owner = User.find_by_id(@parent.user_id)
    end

    def set_parent      
        if params[:repairshop_id]
            @parent =  Repairshop.find_by_id(params[:repairshop_id] )
        end

        if params[:listing_id]
            @parent = Listing.find_by_id(params[:listing_id] )  
        end

        @owner = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    end


end
```

If I set parent by directly giving repairshop_id, everything works fine. But somehow, this repairshop_id is not being passed to the controller set_parent action.

How can I pass a variable from a show page to an entirely new controller action.

I want to redirect the users to the listing/repairshops show page after review creation, from which they clicked on the review button and so trying to use that @parent params

update: The error I am getting is 500 Internal Server, can not redirect to nil (which is @parent here):

[image]

My review form code:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for [@owner, @review] do |f| %>
  <% if @review.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@review.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this review from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @review.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.select :rating, [1,2,3,4,5], :label => "CHOOSE YOUR RATING (1 is poor, 5 is great)" %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment, :label => "YOUR COMMENTS" %>

  <%= f.submit "SUBMIT", class: "btn btn-danger" %>    

<% end %>
```

updated pic:[image]

Comment: Could you please show us exactly what error message you are getting?

Comment: what about http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

Comment: I believe for some reason you can not access the `params` hash in the before filter or in the private method. This must have to do with strong params

Comment: @JunanChakma I have added the screenshot. I am getting a 500 error on redirect.

Comment: In simple terms, Suppose I have http://localhost:3000/users/2/reviews/new?repairshop_id=3 in my URL on new action. How can I pass that repairshop_id to the create action ?

Comment: @SauravPrakash I just checked your log. You are not actually passing `repairshop_id ` while creating a `review`. Please pass `repairshop_id` from `review` form.(You could also add the review form code in the post so that we can help)

Comment: @JunanChakma The review doesn't belong to repairshop so it doesn't need repairshop_id. It belongs to a user. I am using repairshop_id only to redirect to the parent (repairshop page) after the review is created from which it was called

Comment: @SauravPrakash You don't  need `repairshop_id ` to create `review` as it is not belong to `repairshop`. But still you have to pass `repairshop_id` while you hit `create` action to create a `review`. Because your `set_parent` method will be called before `create` action and in `set_parent` method this code(`@parent =  Repairshop.find_by_id(params[:repairshop_id] )`) expecting `repairshop_id` in params. As you are not passing `repairshop_id` while creating `review` that why `@parent` getting nil value and you are getting error while redirecting to `@parent`

Comment: @JunanChakma ohkay! So you mean as hidden params ? have added my review form code above

Comment: @SauravPrakash I have added answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem was to use session params.
A session is just a place to store data during one request that you can read during later requests.

I decided to use session hash to store the resource id params I get from the new link in the resource it was called from and then use the session hash to retrieve the parent to redirect to after a review has been created. Also, I don't need to use hidden fields for this to work.

```
class ReviewsController < InheritedResources::Base

    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :update]     
    before_action :set_child_and_parent, only:  [:destroy, :update, :edit]

    def new
        @review = Review.new                
        session[:parent_id] = params[:parent_id]
        session[:parent_type] = params[:parent_type]
        @parent = get_parent(params[:parent_type], params[:parent_id])      
        @owner = User.find_by_id(@parent.user_id)       
    end

    def create      
        @review = Review.new(review_params)         
        @review.user_id = current_user.id
        @parent = get_parent(session[:parent_type], session[:parent_id])
        @owner = User.find_by_id(@parent.user_id)       
        @review.owner_id = @owner.id             

        respond_to do |format|
            if @review.save 
                format.html { redirect_to @parent, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location:@review }
            else                
                format.html { render :new }
                format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end


private

    def review_params       
        params.require(:review).permit(:comment, :rating)
    end

    def set_child_and_parent        
        @review = Review.find_by_id(params[:id])        
    end

    def get_parent(parent_type, parent_id)
        if parent_type == "repairshop"
            parent = Repairshop.find_by_id(parent_id.to_i)
        elsif parent_type == "listing"
            parent = Listing.find_by_id(parent_id.to_i)
        else
            parent = root_path
        end

        return parent
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

**tips to debug:**

add [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)

```
def set_parent
  byebug
  ..
end
```

then, run the code, and in the byebug console, try `puts params`, `puts params[:review]`

**hint:**

```
def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:comment, :rating, :repairshop_id)
end
```

Comment: I have added the screenshot. I am getting a 500 error on redirect.

Comment: In simple terms, Suppose I have http://localhost:3000/users/2/reviews/new?repairshop_id=3 in my URL on new action. How can I pass that repairshop_id to the create action ?

Answer (score 0):

First in your `new` action set your desired `repairshop_id` something like

```
   def new
     @review = Review.new     
     @repairshop_id = params[:repairshop_id]
   end
```

then add `<%= hidden_field_tag :repairshop_id, @repairshop_id %>` in your form something like

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for [@owner, @review] do |f| %>
  <% if @review.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@review.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this review from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @review.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.select :rating, [1,2,3,4,5], :label => "CHOOSE YOUR RATING (1 is poor, 5 is great)" %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment, :label => "YOUR COMMENTS" %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :repairshop_id, @repairshop_id %>

  <%= f.submit "SUBMIT", class: "btn btn-danger" %>    

<% end %>
```

Comment: The problem still persists!
<%= link_to 'Add A Review', new_user_review_path(@user, :repairshop_id => @repairshop.id), class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs", style: "border: #e20049" %> link is in show.html.erb of repairshop. I click this link, it brings me to the new action of review. Now I want to assign @repairshop_id. Its not 1/2/3 but its the value I get from the previous page. How can I do that?

Comment: Okay, you can assign it like `@repairshop_id = params[:repairshop_id]`. I edited my answer also.

Comment: For this to work I will have  to add repairshop_id param to review model right ? Otherwise its giving me error that repairshop_id is not a param. I just want to redirect the users to that repairshop so don't want to store in database. I tired params.require(:repairshop_id).permit! but it didn't work. 
Just like redirect :back, I want to redirect to the repairshop after review is submitted

Comment: Could you show me the exact error message you are getting now?

Comment: Updated the question and also here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7h6sp.png

Comment: I created a gist. Please check https://gist.github.com/junan/23e0ae7795c93a57c161c213a932ba8d

Comment: Gives me unpermitted parameter error Unpermitted parameter:repairshop_id

Comment: Did you remove this line `params.require(:repairshop_id).permit!` from `review_params` method. if not remove it and restart the server and check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last screenshot,Your review_params method is wrong.

```
def toto
  '1'
  '2'
end

puts toto => you will get 2

def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(...)
  params.require(:repairshop_id).permit(..)
end

puts review_params <--- what will you get ?
```

Likely you want to understand what `require`, and `permit` does, rather giving you a pure answer.

Ex.

```
params = { repairshop_id: '1', review: { rating: '1', comment: 'hello world' }}
puts params.require(:repairshop_id) => { repairshop: '1' }
puts params.require(:review).permit(:rating) => { review: { rating: '1' } }
puts params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment) => { review: { rating: '1', comment: 'Hello World' } }
puts params.require(:toto) => Would raise an exception, saying toto is missing.
```

---

i) Add hidden filed input in your form,

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :repairshop_id, < YOUR REPAIR SHOP ID > %>
```

ii) Fix `review_params` method

```
def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
end
```

iii) Find your repairshop in the create, or before_action as such:

```
before_action :find_repairshop

..


def find_repairshop
  @repairshop = Repairshop.find(params[:repairshop_id])
end
```

Comment: Gives me un-permitted parameter error
Unpermitted parameter:repairshop_id

Comment: that is fine @SauravPrakash. `@repairshop = Repairshop.find(params[:repairshop_id]` should works.